# geoxml3 removing set center position

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, geoxml3

I am loading a KML file using geoxml3. the center position gets applied when google maps loads but once geoxml3 applies the kml file it moves the center position.

```
var myOptions = {
        zoom : 2,
        minZoom:2,
        maxZoom:10,
        center : latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        suppressInfoWindows : true,
        preserveViewport : true
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        singleInfoWindow: false,
        afterParse: useTheData,
        suppressInfoWindows : true,
        center : latlng
    });
    geoXml.parse(url_kml+'basins.kml');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the `zoom`-option of the parser-options to `false`

```
var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        singleInfoWindow: false,
        afterParse: useTheData,
        suppressInfoWindows : true,
        zoom : false
    });
```

https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/ParserReference#geoXML3.parser_Options